# How to resize Chrome Extension and its elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I'm working on a simple **Chrome Extension**. I decided to use **Bootstrap** to help me with design and everything seems to work but the popup window is very high and thin and all elements inside (buttons, forms...) are too huge. It makes sense because the elements are their regular size but in plugin, they should be smaller.

For illustration:

[image]

I tried to put this code into `popup.js`:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('body').height(280);
    $('html').height(280);
});
```

As you can see, the popup should be wider and less smaller.

**popup.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Getting Started Extension's Popup</title>
    <style>
        body {
            font-family: "Segoe UI", "Lucida Grande", Tahoma, sans-serif;
            font-size: 100%;
        }

        #status {
            /* avoid an excessively wide status text */
            white-space: pre;
            text-overflow: ellipsis;
            overflow: hidden;
            max-width: 400px;
        }
    </style>


    <!--
      - JavaScript and HTML must be in separate files: see our Content Security
      - Policy documentation[1] for details and explanation.
      -
      - [1]: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy
     -->

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.15.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap/respond.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap/usebootstrap.js"></script>

    <script src="popup.js"></script>
    <script src="productspy.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">

    <link href="theme/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="theme/usebootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<h1>Product Spy Client</h1>
<h2>Please login:</h2>
<form class="form-signin">
    <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Please sign in</h2>
    <label for="inputEmail" class="sr-only">Email address</label>
    <input type="email" id="inputEmail" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" required="" autofocus="">
    <label for="inputPassword" class="sr-only">Password</label>
    <input type="password" id="inputPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required="">
    <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" value="remember-me"> Remember me
        </label>
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Log in</button>
</form>
<button id="check-conn-button-id" class="btn-primary">Check Connection</button>
</body>
</html>
```

How to resize the window of the popup and smaller the elements so every button and everything would be smaller? Is it possible?

Comment: There is no special magic in case of popups. Right click the popup and use the element inspector to see which rules are actually active for `html` and `body` elements.

Comment: Quick question: did you do the necessary steps to allow loading remote scripts? And why _are_ you loading jQuery remotely? It's likely your code never ran, since jQuery isn't loaded - did you [try to debug](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tut_debugging)?

Answer (score 0):

In your css, inside popup.html.

```
body {
   max-height:280px; 
   width:300px;
   overflow:auto; /* I suppose you want scroll if something happened*/ 
}
```